# How to make a class movable by other classes?

Tags: c++, move, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, move-semantics

Let's say I have an RAII class, like `vector`:

```
class vector{
   double* data_;
   int size_;
public:
   explicit vector(int size = 0) : data_{new double[size]}, size_{size}{}
   vector(vector const& other) : data_{new double[other.size_]}, size_{other.size_}{}
   int size() const{return size_;}
   double const* data() const{return data_;}
   double* data(){return data_;} // optional but common
   ~vector(){if(size_) delete[] double;}
}
```

If I want to make the class moveable I can add a move constructor.

```
   vector(vector&& other) : size_{other.size_}, data_{other.data_}{other.size_ = 0;}
```

So far, modulo typos and pedantic comments, this is all.

However I would like to make the class movable by **other** classes that are unrelated to my `vector`.
I know that basically requires the code similar to the move constructor but in an independent class.

```
class SuperVector{
   double* data_begin_;
   double* data_end_; // I don't use size to show having two independent implementations
   std::string super = "super";
   SuperVector(vector&& v) ... {...} // what here? what needs to change in `vector`?
};
```

I am almost sure that regardless of the `SuperVector` code, `vector` needs somehow to change to allow this.

**The question is if there is a protocol commonly used to allow these moveability from an unrelated class. Or this is something that it is not contemplated yet. (I imagine once in a while people would like to move from an `std::vector` into an unrelated class).**

---

Preliminary work:

The solutions I can imagine are:

1. Make `SuperVector` a **friend** of `vector`, then implement the move "into" simply as

   ```
      SuperVector(vector&& v) : data_begin_{v.data()}, data_end_{v.data() + v.size()}{v.size_ = 0;}
   ```

   The problem with this is that friendship adds to much coupling and it is not a general solution.
2. Give more access to the vector internal representatio (in particular make it assignable).

   ```
      int& vector::size(){return size_;}
   ```

   ```
      SuperVector(vector&& v) : data_begin_{v.data()}, data_end_{v.data() + v.size()}{v.size() = 0;}
   ```

   This is really bad because anybody can change `size`, break invariants, etc.

   Now the more sophisticated and non-trivial options.
3. like 2) but add special functions:

   ```
   class vector{...
      [[nodiscard]] // false sense of security
      double* moved_data()&&{ // for lack of a better name (simply data()&&?)
         size_ = 0;
         return data_;
      }
   ...}
   ```

   and use it as

   ```
      SuperVector(vector&& v){ // or some variation of this
        data_end_ = v.data() + v.size()}; 
        data_begin_ = std::move(v).moved_data();
      }
   ```

   The disadvantage of this is that `vector` needs to be modified, which is expected.
   But also that it seems dangerous that anybody can call `moved_data` and invalidate the `vector`.
   Moreover this depends on `[[nodiscard]]` and can produce a memory leak from unrelated classes.
   Worst of all the `vector` seems to be in a moved from state "prematurely", much before the object is really moved from the (client) other class.

   Finally,
4. maybe what I am missing is some kind of new kind of smart pointer that delays the move to a later time.
   I call it here `move_ptr`.

   ```
   template<class CustomMover>
   class move_ptr{ // or transfer_ptr
      double* ptr_;
      CustomMover mover_;
   public:
      move_ptr(double* ptr, CustomMover mover) : ptr_{ptr}, mover_{std::move(mover)}{}
      // probably movable too.
      [[nodiscard]] operator double*(){ // protect against twice move
         if(ptr_) mover_();
         auto ret = ptr_; ptr_ = nullptr; return ret;
      }
   //   ~move_ptr(){} // if nobody took care, that is ok, nothing happens.
   }
   ```

   ```
   class vector{...
      auto moved_data()&&{ // for lack of a better name (or simply data()&&?)
         auto custom_mover = [&size_]{size_ = 0;};
         return move_ptr<decltype(custom_mover)>{data_, custom_mover_};
      }
   ...}
   ```

   (other posible names are `move()&` or `mdata()&` or `mdata()&&` or `data()&&`.)

   Note that the side effect of the move is carried by the smart pointer.

   and use it as

   ```
      SuperVector(vector&& v){ // or some variation of this
        data_end_ = v.data() + v.size()}; 
        data_begin_ = std::move(v).moved_data(); // this will set size to zero
      }
   ```

   I am sure there are edge cases I am not contemplating by this simplistic code, but I hope the main idea is clear.

   Fixes are welcome.

   **Does this smart pointer make sense or is it there something like this "move manager pointer" already implemented somewhere?**

   I see this is similar to `std::unique_ptr` except that the move is implemented by the copied-from smart pointer and also the custom action happens only on assignment (to a regular pointer).

   Perhaps the same effect can be achieved with `std::unique_ptr` but I don't see how.

This is a concrete application to this more abstract question: [Exact correspondence between r-value references and pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61313437/exact-correspondence-between-r-value-references-and-pointers)

Comment: Maybe you're overthinking this? Do you really need two different vector classes, with the only difference being storing size vs stroring pointer to the end of the buffer?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, no, it is just a simplified example of a more complicated data structure. Even if the representation is the same `data_ + size_` I would have the same problem. The non-overthinking solution you are suggesting is basically that `SuperVector` contained a `vector` and be done with it.

Comment: If I had to do this, I would go with friendship. This is the only way to not expose dirty unsafe functions. Moreover, why do you care about "coupling" ? If you have to move a vector into a SuperVector, they ***are*** coupled/related. You cannot move from the one to the other without making a relation between them. This would not make sense to me.

Comment: The `vector` class needs to expose a way to release its internally managed resource (like `std::unique_ptr` does with [release](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release)), if it does not have that possibility then you either need to store `vector` within `SuperVector` or copy the data. So if it is an option that `SuperVector` uses `vector` as internal storage, and just provides a custom interface to it, then it would be possible.

Comment: An unrelated side-note: Your constructors have undefined behavior because they use `size_` before it is initialized. Remember that members are initialized in the order in which they are declared, *not* in the order in which you write the member initializers.

Comment: @t.niese yes, I figured that out. the question is what a release-like should return given the implementation of vector. (For the second comment, yes, I need to reorder the members or use the arguments differently).

Comment: `I need to reorder the members or use the arguments differently)` that does not prevent you from using your `vector` as storage inside of `SuperVector`. The std library does something similar with `std::queue`, which - as default - uses `std::deque` as internal container and only exposes the functions `std::queue` needs.

Comment: @t.niese yes, I was talking about the vector class constructor. It is an unrelated details as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: About `[…] the question is what a release-like should return given the implementation of vector.[…]` and `[…]if there is a protocol commonly used to allow these moveability from an unrelated class. Or this is something that it is not contemplated yet.[…]` you could think about a template based `swap` but the biggest flaw about that is, that you normally don't want to do that. If you expose internal storage details, you prevent yourself from doing changes to that later and you would be stuck with your design decision, that's why you won't see such constructs often.

Answer (score 2):

You've gone over all the possibilities, and the direct answer to your question is that there is no common protocol that exists.

This answer reviews a few places in the std::lib that allow the transfer of ownership to unrelated types.

**`unique_ptr`**

```
auto p = up.release();
```

The `unique_ptr` `up` has given up ownership of its resource and the client is now responsible for it.

**`unique_lock`**

```
auto m = ul.release();
```

The `unique_lock` `ul` has given up ownership of the locked state of its mutex and the client is now responsible for it.

**The associative and unordered containers**

The `extract` member function looks up a single element (by key or iterator) and releases ownership of the single node in a smart-pointer-like object called `container::node_type`.  This "smart pointer" has a copy of the allocator so that it knows how to destruct itself.  It also gives non-const access to the contained element to the client.  Only const access is available to the key part of the element when it is owned by the container.

Comment: Great, my question just got the HH badge (one or more answers by Howard in less than 24hr).

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I missed the analogy with the node handle. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle. I am going to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

There fundamentally can’t be a general solution. Moving out of a value fundamentally means that you need to know the implementation details of that value’s type, in particular how it manages memory.

So you need to publish these implementation details one way or another (via friendship, or an even more public interface), which is generally not desirable. Either way you’d get a tight coupling between the types, and this is simply not avoidable.

I also don’t think that, even if possible, this would be as generally useful as you seem to think.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured out that the there is no general solution and somehow an implementation detail must be transmitted to the other the class,  that is why the `move_ptr` has a general custom function. But as you say, that it might not be sufficient still because still information about deallocation is not transmitted without extra information. I guess this actually would force to go beyond and almost no other option than implement `vector` with`unique_ptr` in the first place, which doesn't sound that bad.

Comment: I don’t mind coupling in one of the directions. supervector already depends on vector (it already does depend on the interface because of the signature of the example constructor function). Also I don’t mind that supervector depends on the *implementation* of vector.